# How to get names from collection Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-collection

In template Laravel I need to show `name` field from collection:

```
[{"announcement_id":2,"name":"Name1","amount":1},{"announcement_id":2,"name":"Name2","amount":2}]
```

About I want to get the following:

```
<h2>Name1 / Name 2</h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact you can use collection [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) method together with [implode](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-implode) method, so having collection like this:

```
$c = collect([
    (object)["announcement_id" => 2, "name" => "Name1", "amount" => 1],
    (object)["announcement_id" => 2, "name" => "Name2", "amount" => 2],
]);
```

to get the text you want you can use:

```
echo '<h2>' .($c->pluck('name')->implode(' / ')).'</h2>';
```

**EDIT**

As pointed by @Samsquanch in comment you can even use only implode like this:

```
echo '<h2>' .($c->implode('name', ' / ')).'</h2>';
```

Comment: It's actually even easier than that -- `$c->implode('name', ' / ');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Pluck method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) to get an array of all the names.

```
$names = $collection->pluck('name');
```

Then you can just implode the array in your template file

```
<h2>{{ $names->implode(' / ') }}</h2>
```